# Why can I extend a class at runtime by initializing another class by ClassName.__init__(self)

Tags: python, class

I was wondering why can I extend a class at runtime using the following code:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "1"
        ClassB.__init__(self)


class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.punk = "Punk"


test = ClassA()
print(dir(test))
```

This gives me access to test.value and test.punk. But I don't understand why. Thanks.

Comment: __init__ is simply a method that is called automatically upon object creation but it DOES NOT CREATE THE OBJECT, it simply gets an object an sets some attributes. that's why it's not a problem.

Comment: Note that there's a check to stop this in Python 2, but they took it out because they decided it wasn't worth having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassB.__init__` doesn't make any use of `self` that assumes it is actually an instance of `ClassB`, so explicitly calling it on an instance of `ClassA` is legal, though a bit odd. It's not really any different than if you had written

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "1"
        punker(self)

def punker(obj):
    obj.punk = "Punk"
```

`punker` isn't really much different than `ClassB.__init__`, a fact you can see even more readily by defining `ClassB` as

```
class ClassB:
    __init__ = punker
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Obviously I am handing down the object to ClassB which is assigning new things to the self object coming from ClassA. Totally missed that. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't extend `ClassB`, you just executed `ClassB.__init__()` method over your `ClassA` instance. Python doesn't prevent you from adding new properties to any object, case in point:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "1"

test = ClassA()
test.punk = "Punk"
print(dir(test))
```

But that's not extending - that property is available only to your `test` instance. Methods won't be inherited, for example.

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "1"
        ClassB.__init__(self)


class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.punk = "Punk"
    def foo(self):
        print("BAR!")

test = ClassA()
print(test.punk)  # OK
test.foo()  # ERR!
```

Comment: Thanks to you too! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this works is because you are modifying `ClassA`'s `self` parmeter using `ClassB.__init__()`.

When you passed `self` to `ClassB` inside of `ClassA.__init__()`, `ClassB.__init__()` accepted the object passed in an assigned the attribute `punk` to it. *Normally* `self` would have been an instance of `ClassB` because Python implicitly passes the value of `self`. But because you explicitly passed in a different argument - an instance of `ClassA` - Python used that value instead.

This can be seen with a simple example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        B.__init__(self)


>>> class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('The type of self is: ', self)


>>> a = A()
The type of self is:  <__main__.A object at 0x03E9A050>
>>>
```

As @chepner mentioned, its the same as if you used a normal method and called that inside of `ClassA`'s constructor:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        B.method(self)


>>> class B:
    def method(self):
        print('The type of self is: ', self)


>>> a = A()
The type of self is:  <__main__.A object at 0x03E9A670>
>>>
```

Comment: Glad to help @doom4.